# How to store files with CR-LF line endings in git?

Tags: git, newline

I'm developing software under Linux which will be compiled using a Windows-only compiler. I want git to store my files with CR-LF line endings in the repository on Linux to be able to package the sources without changing them to Windows style.

My `.gitattributes` looks like:

```
*.cpp eol=crlf
*.h   eol=crlf
```

I also already tried `core.eol = crlf`.
But git is still using LF line endings when I do checkouts and commits on Linux.

Is there any way to tell git using CR-LF on Linux?

Comment: What is your `core.autocrlf` value is? If true or native, change it to false.

Comment: My `core.autocrlf` was input. Setting to false doesn't seem to help.

Answer (score 0):

Does the windows only compiler get tripped up by lf-only line endings? If not, keep it set to false.

you need only to set auto crlf to true on a repo that will get the working tree set up for the compiler.

Comment: I've yet to find a compiler that gets tripped up by the line endings. Normally the issue is the windows *editors* and diff tools get tripped up.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried this [Linux; git version 2.1.0]
And as best as I can see its working with the following settings:

```
$ cat .gitattributes 
.gitattributes  text
.gitignore  text
*.cpp       text
*.h     text

$ cat ~/.gitconfig 
...
[core]
    autocrlf = false
    safecrlf = true
    eol  = crlf
```

In this configuration, git only allows crlf files into the database and gives a fatal error for lf on `git add`.

Remove the `safecrlf` setting and now `git add` works but now you get a warning for lf-files.

Now `rm` a checked-in file and `reset --hard` gives a crlf file -- irrespective of whether it was checked in as lf or crlf.

I suspect: You have *already* checked in LF-files and now git is giving those.

Please try with the above settings *on a new repo* and let us know if it works.